# OMNet++ 6: How to read real UDP video stream from internet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have been trying to create Hardware in the Loop simulation, in which I want to get video stream from real devices into my simulation and then move those packets further into my network. Is there any existing example of this? or any way in which I can achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `showcases/emulation/videostreaming` folder in your INET instrallation. The text is available [online](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/emulation/videostreaming/doc/).